# Elasticsearch: Distribute the results of multiple inner queries based on defined amount/ percentage

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-query

Consider I am having multiple should blocks, I want to define how many documents each should block can derive. For example if result is set of 10 documents, I need 6 from first block, 3 from second block, 1 from last block.

Comment: @did you get a chance to look into my answer?

Comment: HI @Amit, I checked and accepted the answer

Comment: HI @Amit I have accepted the answer already... 
The right arrow is already clicked...

Comment: @Amit if you are not able to find whether its accepted, please check the screenshot
https://ibb.co/vVKNcHC

Comment: Oh I did it now.

Comment: You got it now :), have a great day ahead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such functionality present in the elasticsearch, if these inner blocks are independent means, they don't impact the search results, than you can use the [multi-search API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) and define the size param with each query separately.